# Viewflow: what's the best/canonical way to get the current pending task?

Tags: django-viewflow, viewflow

I inspected the `Process` model, and found `active_tasks` method:

```py
    def active_tasks(self):
        """List of non finished tasks."""
        return self.flow_class.task_class._default_manager \
            .filter(process=self, finished__isnull=True) \
            .order_by('created')
```

Is this the canonical way to get the pending task by `process_instance.active_tasks.first()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Viewflow allows to have several parallel tasks at the same time, You should define what `next pending task` means by your own in your specific case..

for the reference you could also look at default next user redirect heuristics - https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/viewflow/flow/views/utils.py#L12